# UI elements in Xcode seem to be overlapping with each other. How to fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

So, I'm developing an app in Xcode and have used AutoLayout for this. The layout seems fine in an iPhone 8 but if I look at the same layout in iPhone SE, the elements seem to be overlapping with each other. How should I fix this? Please tell me if you need more details!

[image: My screenshot]

Comment: Does this also happen when running the app on a device / simulator?

Comment: Yeah scrollview solve this problem but never set height constraint for scrollview but inside the component reside inthe scrolllview you can set dyanmic or static height .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you want to support devices like iPhone 4/5 with your current long view , then you need to insert it inside a scrollview , as iPhone 8 height is longer it stretches freely , but for small devices , constraints will break and you'll get unexpected results

Comment: Ahh! I see! Thanks for this!